# Maven archetype that creates a webapp with WAR generation, eclipse web project, JUnit, command-line Jetty

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I often need to create Java webapps.

I usually run the `maven-archetype-webapp` archetype, but it does not provide enough, so I always have to manually add many things, such as jetty:run. I want to reduce all of these steps to a minimum, meaning I would be able to use the project directly after archetype generation without having to add more dependencies or plugins to the `pom.xml` file.

Requirements:

- Webapp structure (Servlet 3.1 or later)
- WAR generation command
- JUnit command/dependencies
- Logging (can be SLF4J or Log4j or logback or java.util.logging
- WTP Eclipse Web project (Not just a normal Eclipse project. Should work on latest released Eclipse version)
- Command to run the server (probably using Jetty or similar), I don't have to configure anything, I just run the command and the webapp gets launched
- Does not add other things, in particular no particular framework

Comment: The [Maven archetypes](https://vaadin.com/maven#archetypes) for [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com) do all that, come with a copy of Jetty bundled for running your web app from within your project, plus provides a proven free-of-cost open-source framework to build a web app user-interface using only pure Java. See [Getting Started](https://vaadin.com/framework/get-started).